# Typescript - Multi list map() function

Tags: arrays, typescript

Is there a function similar to map() that can take more then one array as input.

I am talking about something like this:

```
arr1 = [0,1,2];
arr2 = [2,4,6];

result = [arr1, arr2].multiMap((item1, item2) => item1 + item2);

console.out(result);

// output: [2,5,8]
```

I'm sure that it should exist, but I just cant find it.

Comment: No, it doesn't exist. It can be trivially implemented *using* `map`, though or using a third party library, if you wish.

Comment: pretty easy solution with simple for loop... no need to complicate it

Comment: @JurajKocan, Thank you for the sugestion. I know it can be done, but I was looking for a more compact and readable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. But `map` function's callback gets three parameters, not just one, and the second one is the index, which you can use to get the corresponding elements of parallel arrays. (The third one is the array itself, and can be ignored.)

```
result = arr1.map((item1, i) => item1 + arr2[i])
```

or more readably and sliiiightly less performantly

```
result = arr1.map((_, i) => arr1[i] + arr2[i])
```